# Error Processing SSAS Dimension with Netezza Data Source

Tags: sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence, netezza, sql-server-data-tools

I am in the middle of a migration project of a DW from MSSQL to Netezza and I am stuck in a problem which I'm positive it's ridiculous to solve, but I have failed hardly on trying to do so. I was hoping you guys could enlighten me up regarding this issue.

Part of this migration is to refactor the applications that queried MSSQL to query Netezza now, and I am currently trying to redeploy and test the SSAS Cubes using Netezza as one of it's data sources to retrieve data and process the dimensions.

I have already set the DS properties properly using Netezza OLEDB driver and connected successfully via "Test Connection". Also, on Visual Studio, I was able to edit the named query of the desired dimensions and run them without any errors.

But my problem now is that whenever I deploy the solution and try to process this dimension in SQL Management Studio I keep getting the

> "Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be
>   made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'RDW_DS'"

I've been told this error might be related to my `ImpersonationMode`. When I change the data source to the original MSSQL DW and use my Windows domain account, it works perfectly, but since AD isn't federated in the Netezza PDA appliance, I am using the admin user/pass credentials.

Do you guys have any suggestion on how to handle this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Enrico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow found a way to get it working! I had to install the NZ .NET Driver to get the NZOLEDB driver to work properly, then I could run the processing using my windows domain user with privileges on the MSSQL server as ImpersonationMode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error initially.

I have developed cube(Data Source - Netezza) in Visual Studio 2010 and I when I tried to deploy the cube in SSAS server, I got the exact same error. Another error was : Errors in the back-end database module. The provider 'NZOLEDB' not registered.

The driver information is in the picture attached. The driver was installed on my machine locally but was missing in the server. Requested DBA to install in SSAS Server and I was able to connect successfully after that. The diver has to be properly installed locally and SSAS Server. [image: Screenshot]

I was able to process and deploy the cube. Impersonation Information: Inherit. [image: Screenshot]